# Using a Navigation Drawer to Switch Activites?

Tags: android, android-activity, navigation-drawer

So, I have 3 activities that I want to link with a Navigation drawer but I'm exactly sure how to do that. I saw somewhere that I should make a new class for the Navigation Drawer methods or something like that but I didn't really understand. So, what would be a good way to do this?

By the way, I'm very new to android development...

Comment: I would highly suggest using the `NavigationDrawer` example that comes with `Android Studio` and use `Fragments`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simple, if you check the navigation drawer of Google examples, they load a fragment when you click in an item.

Just change it, and use for each item:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Change the activities names for each one of your three activities.

Here an example of how to do it:
[Navigation Drawer](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/)

In this part you have to change the code that I mentioned before:

```
 /**
 * Slide menu item click listener
 * */
private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // display view for selected nav drawer item
        displayView(position);
    }
}

 /**
 * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
 * */
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    case 1:
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    case 2:
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    case 3:
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ForthActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you should make a new activity in which the navigation-drawer is used, and then convert the 3 activities to fragments. In this way, you can navigation between this 3 fragments, This is the recommended pattern to navigate between some Top level "View".